# What is the formal synonym of "taking over the property"

Tags: vocabulary

I'm writing a text and am confused about a word I knew before.

The definition is : to Take away the property of someone (by government or bank or a legal institution).

I have found seize or take over, but I know there is better word for it which I had used in my translations before.

Can any one suggest a better word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Confiscate.**

Wikipedia [defines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confiscation) "confiscate" as-

> Confiscation, from the Latin confiscatio 'joining to the fiscus, i.e.
>   transfer to the treasury' is a legal seizure by a government or other
>   public authority. The word is also used, popularly, of spoliation
>   under legal forms, or of any seizure of property as punishment or in
>   enforcement of the law

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/confiscate)-

> con·fis·cate  (knf-skt)
>
> tr.v. con·fis·cat·ed, con·fis·cat·ing, con·fis·cates
>
> To seize (private property) for the public treasury.
>   To seize by or as if by authority

Answer (score 2):

Googling "seize synonym" suggests (among other things): confiscate, take possession of, etc. I guess you had "confiscate" in mind.

Comment: Give a man a fish...

Answer (score 2):

Here are three more from Collins:

> **sequester** vb (tr)
>
> ...
>   3. (Law) law to take (property) temporarily out of the possession of its owner, esp until the claims of creditors are satisfied or a court
>   order is complied with
>   4. (Law) international law to **requisition** or **appropriate** (enemy property)

Answer (score 2):

The term  *condemn* is relevant.  From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/condemn#Verb):

> (5) To determine and declare (property) to be assigned to public use. See eminent domain.
>   (7) To declare (a vessel) to be forfeited to the government, to be a prize, or to be unfit for service.

Note, *[eminent domain](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eminent_domain#Noun)* as mentioned above refers to  “The right of a government over the lands within its jurisdiction. Usually invoked to compel land owners to sell their property in preparation for a major construction project such as a freeway”.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on  the context, also [expropriate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Expropriate) may fit:

> - (Law) to deprive (an owner) of (property), esp by taking it for public use.
>     From Medieval Latin expropriāre to deprive of possessions, from proprius own]

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expropriate

Answer (score 1):

Simply because no one has suggested it yet, and it's quite common:

> ***foreclose***: take possession of a mortgaged property as a result of the mortgagor's *failure to keep up their mortgage payments*.

Related:

> ***repossess***: retake possession of (something) when a buyer *defaults on payments*.